# fontFamily Unknown resource type Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, fonts

i use Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3

how i fix this error **Unknown resource type fonts**

textview code

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/descTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@fonts/zaxo"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_size"
            app:font='@{"normal"}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
            tools:text="Description"/>
```

i also created folder font see picture [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcdDz.png)

[see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU0mO.png)

i also added this line in style.xml

```
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@fonts/zaxo</item>
```

and also i added added my font to Utils.java

```
  public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, Fonts fonts) {

       if (currentTypeface == fonts) {
           if (fromAsset == null) {
               if (fonts == Fonts.NOTO_SANS) {
                   fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
               } else if (fonts == Fonts.ROBOTO) {
//                    fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
                   fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf");
               } else if (fonts == Fonts.ROBOTO_MEDIUM) {
                   fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Bold.ttf");
               } else if (fonts == Fonts.ROBOTO_LIGHT) {
                   fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf");
               } else if (fonts == Fonts.MM_FONT) {
                   fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/mymm.ttf");
               }
               else if (fonts == Fonts.KURDI) {
                   fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/zaxo.ttf");
               }

           }
       } else {
           if (fonts == Fonts.NOTO_SANS) {
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
           } else if (fonts == Fonts.ROBOTO) {
//                fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf");
           } else if (fonts == Fonts.ROBOTO_MEDIUM) {
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Bold.ttf");
           } else if (fonts == Fonts.ROBOTO_LIGHT) {
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf");
           } else if (fonts == Fonts.MM_FONT) {
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/mymm.ttf");
           } else if (fonts == Fonts.KURDI) {
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/zaxo.ttf");
           } else {
               fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf");
           }


           //fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf");
           currentTypeface = fonts;
       }
       return fromAsset;
   }

   public static SpannableString getSpannableString(Context context, String str, Fonts font) {
       spannableString = new SpannableString(str);
       spannableString.setSpan(new PSTypefaceSpan("", Utils.getTypeFace(context, font)), 0, spannableString.length(),
               Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       return spannableString;
   }
```

when i click this icon i did not find my font
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8Ej.png)

thanks

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Caches and Restart, and after this, Clean Build? Often Android Studio shows those problems because there're something on cache in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep the 'font' folder under 'res' folder and also it is 'font' not 'fonts'

[check this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) on how to add fonts